# Viewing debug output from an external library with XNA

Tags: c#, debugging, xna

I am writing an XNA library, and I need to view its debug output when I run the XNA game which calls its functions.  This worked fine when I hosted it within a console application - I could just use Console.Writeline().  Is there an equivalent way to do this when the functions are being called from a non-console application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) form TechNet (formerly a SysInternals tool) will capture debug output.

> DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output on your
>   local system, or any computer on the network that you can reach via
>   TCP/IP. It is capable of displaying both kernel-mode and Win32 debug
>   output, so you don't need a debugger to catch the debug output your
>   applications or device drivers generate, nor do you need to modify
>   your applications or drivers to use non-standard debug output APIs.

Instead of using `Console.Writeline()`, use `Debug.WriteLine()` (and compile for debug) or better still  a standard logging library such as Log4Net.

[How to trace and debug in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)

[XNA: Debugging tips?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17155/debugging-tips)